# Linkable blocks of text in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I encoutered an essential problem while making an iPad app, where u HUGE amount of text will be displayed.
I need to create blocks of text that can line break and also be linkable(for calling certain functions on each block). I thought that Core Text should be used. 
**Which is the way to assign the position of touch with necessary block of text?**

and does anyone has any examples? google is poor on it, when it's about working with some amounts of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a transparent button in overlay of the text.

Comment: Yes, it's usually a good practice, but text is shown dinamically, the size and positon will be changed, and the button just cant follow the text.  i'll edit the main question...

Comment: If you can get the coordinate of your text you can make a button with dynamic size and position

Answer (score 0):

You can not make your text linkable as in a html page. You can do this feature only in Webview.

Comment: It's good idea, but i have a HUGE text, and i will have a HUGE amount of handlers created dinamically, so with webview it will take a "while". I am planning to catch the coordinates of the touch, and run the needed hadnler by comparing the touch coordinates with block's info.